# enabling Picamera with Ubuntu 20.04 aarch64 on Raspberry pi 4

Tags: raspberrypi

I've been trying to find a way to enable the Picamera with Ubuntu aarch64 on Raspberry pi 4 module but so far I only found how to do it on Raspberry pi 2/3,
or with arch32.

Is there a way to support Picamera with Ubuntu 20.04 aarch64 on Raspberry pi 4 module?

Comment: have you tried installing from source code?
also you might enjoy the raspberry pi stackexchange, this question clearly belongs there.
read this: https://larrylisky.com/2016/11/24/enabling-raspberry-pi-camera-v2-under-ubuntu-mate/

Comment: Sorry, it’s 20.04

Comment: This question is also on topic here.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it will work. Picamera functions under aarch64.
The answer  is here - https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/114035/picamera-and-ubuntu-20-04-arm64

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture('/dev/video0', cv2.CAP_V4L)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 2560)
cap.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 1440)
ret, frame = cap.read()
cv2.imwrite('image.jpg', frame)
cap.release()
```

Run the python script after installing opencv. It should save a photo in the same directory as the script.
I just tested on Raspberry PI 4 B, Ubuntu Server 20.04 64 bit (with Desktop) with OpenCV all good.

If you still have issues, make sure boot/config.txt has,

```
 start_x=1
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install the **raspi-config** tool for Ubuntu 22.04 and 20.04.

In a terminal type below command to install the tool.

```
sudo apt install raspi-config
```

Then open the tool using

```
sudo raspi-config
```

Once the tool screen is openwed, go to Interface Options and then enable "Legacy camera option".

More about raspi-config tool [Raspberry Pi Documentation](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html)